# How to Authenticate client-side calls to Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, mern

I cannot authenticate my client-side calls to my Firebase Realtime Database.

Link to a page on my MERN application [qupp](https://qupp.2112staging.com/playlist/5cd33d4e8b63fc5648f48182) where you can get an idea of how the site works (please note I'm only building this for experimentation purposes, there are holes in the logic idea of this app). Feel free to search and add songs.

My application allows any anonymous users to visit my site, search for songs via Spotify’s API and add that song/data to a queue on my site that is persisted using Firebase(Firebase and syncState so its real time and multiple users can all be adding to the queue at the same time). While this is public I want to lock down the Firebase Database so only my website can write to it.

This would stop hackers from deleting/manipulating data in the queue.

At the moment my Firebase Database Rules are all set to read/write: true. If I set them to be secure like “auth !== null” then I of course cannot no longer write to the DB from my site. But I can’t figure out how to authenticate my calls without having each user sign into my site.

```
"rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
}
```

Note. Firebase is used client side in my app(as it works with React to sync the state) and so I don’t believe I can use firebase-admin SDK to authenticate my server and thus make authenticated calls.

An idea I had is that whenever my app is initialised (in my base.js file) I sign in here so then my Firebase app is authenticated but I cannot find anyway to do this.

client/src/base.js

```
import Rebase from 're-base';
import firebase from 'firebase';

const {
    FIREBASE_API_KEY
} = process.env;

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: "qupp-xxxx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://qupp-xxxx.firebaseio.com"
});

const base = Rebase.createClass(firebaseApp.database());

export { firebaseApp };

export default base;
```

My intended result is that my site can write to my Firebase Database when the rules are set to:

```
"rules": {
    ".read": “auth !== null”,
    ".write": “auth !== null”
  }
```

Comment: "An idea I had is that whenever my app is initialised (in my base.js file) I sign in here so then my Firebase app is authenticated but I cannot find anyway to do this." this could easily be done with the `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` method (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithemailandpassword) but it means the mail and password will be include in the front-end code!

Comment: @RenaudTarnec, what if email and password were stored in the .env file? Thus not in my front-end code.

Comment: Which .env file are you referring to? Where is it stored? If you call the `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` method from your front-end, passing the user email and password, these values will be (need to be) in the front-end code and could be read by an "evil" user that could easily use them to authenticate to your database (since your `firebaseApp` object, i.e. the Firebase config, is also available in the front-end code).

Comment: My local .env file which is hidden from Git and thus not in my code and on staging and production it would be in the servers .env file and so still not in the front-end code. That would work right? Going to try `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` now.

Comment: Actually I don't know reactjs but what I am 99,99% sure is that if you want to call, from your front-end, the `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` method with some **constant** parameters you need to include them in your font-end code and it will be possible to find their values. (This will definitely be the case with other SPA framework like Vue.js). Usually you pass to this method some values that come from a form, where the user has keyed-in the desired values.

Comment: I am not sure there is a solution for your requirement, even with passing through another server and using the admin-sdk. You only want authorised users to create content but you don't want to authenticate them... seems not feasible!

Comment: Hi Renaud, would you like to put your suggestion into an answer as it worked and seems to solve my issue.